# How do I sort a JSON date in javascript?

Tags: javascript

The problem I encounter is that the .sort function doesn't work in my code.
So I am wondering why and I also would like to know the solution.

Here is my full code. So I have a set of json data with username, text message, and a date when the user texted. I am able to display the data, but now I want to order them by date.

```
/**
 * Call to load the test messages.
 */
function loadTestMessages() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'data/testmessages.json', true);

    request.onload = function () {
        if (request.status == 200) {
            var messages = JSON.parse(request.response);
            showAllMessages(messages);
        } else {

            console.error("could not load testmessages.json");
        }
    };

    request.onerror = function () {
        console.error("could not load testmessages.json");
    };

    request.send();
}

/**
 * Make a "block" div
 */
function messageDiv(kindClass, html) {
    return '<div class="' + kindClass + '">' + html + '</div>';
}

/**
 * Display all messages 
 * @param {Array} messages
 */
function showAllMessages(messages) {

    for (i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        var name = messages[i].user_id;
        var content = messages[i].content;
        var date = messages[i].created_at;
        var container = document.getElementById('container');
        //   date.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b });
        //   console.info(date);
        container.innerHTML += messageDiv('block', name + ': </br> ' + content + ' </br> ' + date + ' </br> ');
    }

}

loadTestMessages();
```

Comment: Can you show the values of `start`? Maybe they're not in a format that JS can parse.

Comment: `created_at` is typically not an array value but `sort()` is an array method. This sounds like an XY Problem

Comment: Also, we need to know what the value of `messages[i].created_at` is. The way your code is written, it appears that `created_at` could be an array. So I can't tell if your sort function is the problem, or if it is the way you're looping through the messages.

Comment: 1. JSON doesn't have a date type. 2. You aren't using JSON here anyway. You are using JavaScript objects. 3. It doesn't make sense to "sort a date". It only makes sense to "sort an array by a date value". 4. Do you really want to sort just `messages[i].created_at` or do you want to sort the entire `messages` array?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to sort the `messages` array by the `created_at` date. If that is correct, you can do it in one line:

```
messages.sort(function (a, b) { return b.created_at - a.created_at; })
```

This assumes that `created_at` holds a `Date` object. If it is a string instead, then you have to parse it to a `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a best guess based on your code, but I think you need to sort messages based on the date, then write out the HTML

```
function showAllMessages(messages) {
    //Sort messages based on the date
    messages.sort(function (m1, m2) { return new Date(m1.created_at) - new Date(m2.created_at) });

    var html = '';
    for (i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        var name = messages[i].user_id;
        var content = messages[i].content;
        var date = messages[i].created_at;
        html += messageDiv('block', name + ': </br> ' + content + ' </br> ' + date + ' </br> ');
    }

    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    container.innerHTML += html;
}
```

Comment: Really no need to use `getTime()` since date objects will be cast to number anyway when using `-` operator

Comment: Note that you can subtract dates directly. You don't need to call `getTime()`.

Comment: I wasn't sure that I could assume that created_at was already a date based on the code... So I just left it as the OP had it.

Comment: That said, I am now realizing that the OP was using the `start` property, so.. I can't know for sure until we get more info.

Comment: Right but `new Date(m1.created_at) -  new Date(m2.created_at` is effectively same thing without needing `getTime()`

Comment: Oh gotcha.. I understand what you meant now. I was thinking that `getTime()` was getting the actual time portion of the date, rather than the entire date/time.

Comment: @charlietfl It is indeed the same thing and we all love that JS can implicitly cast things but `.getTime()` is perfectly acceptable for semantic reasons. And OP uses it so he can see what is really needed to fix his code.

Answer (score -3):

```
date.sort(function (a, b) { return new Date(b.start).getTime() = new Date(a.start).getTime() });
```

Comment: Syntax doesn't make sense and you didn't provide any explanation. Code only answers aren't very helpful without an explanation of why your changes would help solve OP's issue

Comment: Why do you use `=` here? Did you mean `-`? If so, then you have exactly the same thing as the OP, so it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: While what you have written may answer the question, however it does seem a little lacking in [explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) and may illicit confusion to other users. Can you please expand upon your answer so that it is clearer and more accessible? This will make for better answers and help future users understand how the problem was solved.